# Matching patterns without unification in Prolog

Tags: prolog, pattern-matching, iso-prolog

I need to match one pattern with several different terms in Prolog, but I don't want to unify any of the variables when matching them. I found one possible way to do this, but it seems inefficient:

```
:- initialization(main).
:- set_prolog_flag('double_quotes','chars').

main :-
    Pattern = (A>B;B<A),
    match_without_unify(Pattern,(1>A1;A1<1)),
    match_without_unify(Pattern,(2>4;4<2)).

match_without_unify(A,B) :-
    %copy the terms, unify them, and count the number of variables
    copy_term([A,B],[A1,B1]),
    term_variables(B1,L1),
    length(L1,L),
    A1=B1,
    term_variables(B1,L2),
    length(L2,L),
    writeln([L1,L2]).
```

Is it possible to solve this problem without calling `term_variables/2` and `length/2` twice?

Comment: When exactly do you consider something a match? Is `A =?= 2` a match? or should it be `A =?= B`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem If `A` is a free variable, then `match_without_unify(A,2)` succeeds, but `match_without_unify(2,A)` fails. It works as intended.

Comment: You can test if a match is possible with [subsumes_term/2](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/dtc2#subsumes_term).

Comment: BTW, your definition is most probably incorrect: Instead of taking the length, better test `L1 == L2`

Comment: Here is a minimal counterexample: `match_without_unify(-X,Z).`  succeeds incorrectly. But I presume you want it to fail. Note that `subsumes_term(-X,Z).` fails as you probably expect.

Comment: @false Yes, it seems to work correctly when I test `L1 == L2` instead of using `length/2`. `subsumes_term/2` is probably the predicate that I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need here is called *syntactic one-sided unification*. This is provided via the ISO-builtin 
[`subsumes_term(General, Specific)`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/dtc2#subsumes_term) which

> ... is true iff there is a substitution θ such that
>
> > a) `General`θ and `Specific`θ are identical, and
> >     b) `Specific`θ and `Specific` are identical

Note that the notion of matching is usually only defined with `Specific` being ground. In such a context it suffices to demand that

> `General`θ and `Specific` are identical

There are various ways how this kind of matching may be extended, but most of the time the fine print is neglected as in the case when 
the condition of `Specific` being ground is simply discarded. This leads to quite unexpected behaviour since `General = X, Specific = s(X)` now "match", with θ = {`X → s(X)`}.

In (old) systems that do not provide `subsumes_term/2`, it can be easily implemented like so:

```
subsumes_term(General, Specific) :-
   \+ General \= Specific, % optimization, which sometimes makes it slower ...
   \+ \+ (  term_variables(Specific, Vs1),
            General = Specific,
            term_variables(Specific, Vs2),
            Vs1 == Vs2
         ).
```

A faster implementation may avoid full unification and the creation of the variable lists. This implementation requires rational tree unification. Replace `\=` and `=` using `unify_with_occurs_check/2` in an ISO-implementation that does not support rational trees.

Answer (score 1):

Your question has an affirmative answer:

> solve this problem without calling term_variables/2 and length/2 twice?

A fastfail solution is found in an utility. The solution by @false   has the drawback that
it calls `General = Specific`, which might unneccessarely perform a full unification
also in cases where pattern matching fails.

```
subsumes(X, Y) :-
    term_variables(Y, S),
    subsumes(X, Y, S).

subsumes(X, Y, S) :- var(X), member(V, S), V == X, !,
    X == Y.
subsumes(X, Y, _) :- var(X), !,
    X = Y.          %  binds
subsumes(X, Y, S) :-
    nonvar(Y),          %  mustn't bind it
    functor(X, F, A), functor(Y, G, B),
    F/A = G/B,
    X =.. [_|L],
    Y =.. [_|R],
    subsumes_list(L, R, S).

subsumes_list([], [], _).
subsumes_list([X|L], [Y|R], S) :-
   subsumes(X, Y, S),
   subsumes_list(L, R, S).
```

Loosly after Richard O'Keefes:
http://www.picat-lang.org/bprolog/publib/metutl.html